# What is known about higher-categorical reconstruction theorems? (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, rt.representation-theory

The answer to my question is almost certainly "not much" — at least, I've asked a few people, and that was their answer.  But I'd like to refine this answer, and MathOverflow seems like the best place.

I learned from David Ben-Zvi in an answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31742/is-a-groupoid-determined-by-its-hopfish-algebra) the following theorem:

> Let $\mathcal C$ be a 1-category, and consider the category $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathcal C)$ of 1-functors $\mathcal C \to \operatorname{1Vect}$.  It is a (symmetric) monoidal category by "pointwise tensor product", i.e. pulling back along the diagonal map $\mathcal C \to \mathcal C^{\times 2}$.  Conversely, we can consider some sort of "spec" of $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathcal C)$, namely the category of *monoidal* functors (and monoidal natural transformations) $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathcal C) \to \operatorname{1Vect}$.  In fact, this "spec" is equivalent as a category to $\mathcal C$.

Given this, it is natural to ask the following three questions (or combinations thereof):

- Recognition: which monoidal categories are of the form $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathcal C)$ for some $\mathcal C$?
- Bump up $n$: modulo definitions, it is clear what the statement is with "$1$" replaced by "$n$".  For example, the "$0$" version of the above says that a *set* is recoverable *up to isomorphism* from its algebra of all functions (the 0-category $\operatorname{0Vect}$ is precisely the ground field).
- Internalize: is there a similar statement for "topological categories" and "continuous functors", for example?  A version of in algebrogeometric land is in [these](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16257/how-to-unify-various-reconstruction-theorems-gabriel-rosenberg-tannaka-balmers) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3446/tannakian-formalism/3467#3467) (see also the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30453/does-the-tannaka-krein-theorem-come-from-an-equivalence-of-2-categories)).

I'm not asking for definite answers to any of these directions, because I expect that telling the complete story is hard.  But I am hoping for references to the existing literature.  Hence: "What's already known (in the literature) about higher-categorical reconstruction theorems?"

Comment: I don't know about monoidal categories, but many dg categories are of the form Mod(A) where A is a dg algebra... See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33877/hochschild-cohomology-of-a-and-of-mod-a

Comment: Incidentally, I lied a bit in the statement of the "theorem" above.  When defining "spec", or at least this "spec with residue field $\rm Vect$", of a monoidal cocomplete linear category like ${\rm Rep}C$, I think that one should insist that the functors to $\rm Vect$ be not just ("strongly") monoidal but also cocontinuous.  This is like insisting that an algebra homomorphism respect not just multiplication but also addition.

Answer (score 4):

In his PhD, Giorgio Trentinaglia
(see http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3394)
considers the reconstruction of an orbifold groupoid from its category of "representations".

At first, one might guess that "representation" means vector bundle.
But Trentinaglia works with a larger category of non-locally-trivial vector bundles: 
the dimension is allowed to jump.

Wether or not the same reconstruction result holds true with actual vector bundles depends on the *global quotient conjecture* that claims that every orbifold is a global quotient by a compact Lie group.